# PySpark - Select dataframe.select if column exists

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I basically have a procedure where I make multiple calls to an API and using a token within the JSON return pass that pack to a function top call the API again to get a "paginated" file.

This all works fine until I get to the final call, because my statement is expecting a column (json value) that no longer exists because its the end of the paginated collection.

How can I test for the existence of the field before I attempt to do a dataframe.select that doesn't return the column and thus fails my procedure.

Schema Example

```
root
 |-- d: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- __next: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- __metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- uri: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- assignmentClass: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- assignmentIdExternal: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- compInfoNav: struct (nullable = true)
```

My code

```
df = df.select(col('d.__next').alias("nexttoken"), explode(col('d.results')).alias("result"))
```

Essentially during the loop at some point the __next value will disappear, but I still use this code it obviously then doesn't find it and errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to check for the existence of `__next` field before using `DataFrame.select()`, you can use the following code. This code specifically works for the schema that you havee provided.

```
d_fields = df.schema['d'].dataType.fieldNames() 

# Type of d_fields is 'list', its values are String type
# In your case, d_fields has values ['__next', 'results'] 

if('__next' in d_fields): 
    df = df.select(col('d.__next').alias("nexttoken"), explode(col('d.results')).alias("result"))
```

When we use `df.schema[‘d’].dataType.fieldNames()` it returns a list of all the fields present in the `d:struct` column. So, you can use `if conditional statement` to check if `'__next'` exists in this list or not. At some point in the loop, when the `d.__next` field is no longer available, the if condition fails and does not throw an error.

Comment: Thank you for a clear and informative answer :)